# Derivative in calculus $f(t)= 7\sinh(\ln t)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to find the derivative of this function $$ 7\sinh(\ln t)?$$

I don't know from where to start, so i looked at it in wolfram alpha and it was saying that the $$ 7((-1 + t^2) / 2t) $$ I did not get that. How did they jump from $$ 7\sinh(\ln t) $$ to this step? Is there an equation for it that I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$\sinh (\ln t)=\frac{e^{\ln t}-e^{-\ln t}}{2}=\frac{t-\frac{1}{t}}{2}=\frac{t^2-1}{2t}$$

Comment: so what will it be? because my answer was 7/2( -(1/t) +t) and it shows wrong

Comment: If you want the derivative of this, it's of course $(2t(2t)-2(t^2-1))/(4t^2)$ (derivative of a quotient $u/v$ is $(u'v-uv')/v^2$).

Answer (score 4):

As Jean-Claude has shown you:

$$f(x) = \sinh (\ln t)=\frac{e^{\ln t}-e^{-\ln t}}{2}=\frac{t-\frac{1}{t}}{2}=\frac{t^2-1}{2t}$$

So $$7\sinh (\ln t)=\frac{e^{\ln t}-e^{-\ln t}}{2}=\frac{t-\frac{1}{t}}{2}=\frac{7(t^2-1)}{2t}$$

So Wolfram has not returned the value of the *derivative* of $f(x)$; it gave you an alternative representation of $f(x)$.  Now, using the quotient rule, you can find $$f'(x) = \left(\frac{7(t^2-1)}{2t}\right)' = \frac 72 \cdot \dfrac{(t^2 - 1)'\cdot t - (t^2 - 1)\cdot (t)'}{(t)^2}$$ $$ = \frac 72 \frac {2t\cdot t - (t^2 - 1)\cdot 1}{t^2}$$ $$ = \frac 72\cdot \frac{2t^2 - t^2 + 1}{t^2} $$ $$= \frac 72\cdot \frac{t^2 + 1}{t^2} = \frac 72\left(1+ \frac 1{t^2}\right)$$

Comment: WOW! Thaaaanks that is really helpful too :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer seems to be wrong. Are you sure from it ?

Comment: I fixed it: I forgot that I had removed the $7/2$ before differentiating the fraction. I'm quite sure we're good now.

Comment: Why not just distribute the division by $t$ before differentiating?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the derivatives of $\ln t$ and $\mathrm{sinh} t$, then you can use the Chain Rule, which states that $(f\circ g)'(t)=g'(t)f'(g(t))$.